# C++ | How to remove rounding after point with precision?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I wrote this code:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh785.png)
for example for test
2 3
it should output 0.66666666 but it outputs 0.66666667
So how can i treat that rounding in the end of my double value?

Comment: Print more digits into a stringstream, chop off the ones you don't want.

Comment: If you truncate the trailing 7 or replace it with with 6 you are applying  your own rounding method.  In a base-10 floating point format the number can not be represented without rounding.